# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined at HTMLButtonElement.removeItem (script.js:26)

Tags: javascript

Here Checked is UNDEFINED and I cannot use this property:

```
function removeItem() {
  li = ul.children;
  for (let index = 0; index < li.length; index++) {
    while (li[index].children[0].checked) {
        ul.removeChild(li[index]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you provide some more code with HTML and js

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. It is very valuable if you know how to debug a program to 
investigate the current program state. Start using the F12 tools in the browser you use for example.

Comment: It has nothing to do with checked, it is because someone does not have a child..... `li[index].children[0]` is `undefined`. The while loop also makes no sense.